# Group WhatsApp API: sending group messages without being listed in the group

Tags: messaging, whatsapp

I am trying to understand something about WhatsApp group messaging API for businesses.
The question is: In order to send a message to a group as a business, does my business user have to explicitly be a member of that group?
In other words, I want to create a group with a few of my customers via the API, but to post messages there without the need to have my business user to be explicitly listed among the group members.

I went over their official docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/group/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/groups/

I also read this post (on which I would comment - if I had enough reputation) : 
[How to send message on WhatsApp Group using official API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189793/how-to-send-message-on-whatsapp-group-using-official-api)

I didn't find an answer on this question there.
Does anyone know?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The feature that you're looking for is the equivalent of 'broadcast' feature on Android and iOS WhatsApp Apps. This is currently not supported by the WhatsApp API client.

Sending a message through group is similar to creating a group on the phone Apps and sending the message. Just like you can't send a message to the group without being its member, you can't do that using the group API on the API client either.